# mysqldump causing database to get not saved records

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqldump

I wish there was a safe way to backup mysql database. The database itself is getting not saved records if the records was about to be saved duding the dump. It is happening occasionally, maybe when the record is saved at the same time when the according DB table is being scanned for dumping.

Because of it, I'm afraid of making backup in a single transaction, I guess it will increase the chances of having lost records.

I use AWS RDS mySQL 5.6.44 and MySql-Workbench to make a dumb from production database, when the PHP scripts are busy making records. (InnoDB)

Is it expected?

Comment: that is why you should put your webpage for the time f the backup into maintanance mode. if you can't stop the webpage, start thinking about replication, and backup only the replicate

Comment: with AWS replication and backups are handled behind the scene. But occasionally I need a fresh snapshot of the database and I have no access neither to replicates, nor to backups.